# Visual Studio Mac extra text after click any key to continue

Tags: c#, macos, console-application, visual-studio-mac

So I have a console application through visual studio on my Mac and after I “press any key to continue” I get extra text after it saying:

```
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Does anybody know what this is or how to hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your Mac telling you that the current `Bash` session has ended.

You'll see the same thing if you open `Terminal` and then type: `exit`:

```
$ exit
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...322 completed.

[Process completed]
```

So, this is not a Visual Studio thing at all. Visual Studio finished the application that it was running in the `Bash` context, and then cleanly closed that session.

Comment: So there’s no way to stop it from saying that?

Comment: Well, how are you running the app? From inside Visual Studio, in Debug Mode? I think that once you build the app and it becomes a standalone executable, if you run it from Terminal, then you won't see that message anymore. Try "Build"ing your app, and then running it directly from the Terminal. See if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your console project so that it does not use the separate terminal window and instead all output goes to the Application Output window inside Visual Studio for Mac.

1. Right click your project in the Solution window and select Options.
2. Select Run - Configurations - Default.
3. Uncheck Run on external console.
4. Click the OK button to save the changes.

Then when you run or debug the console project the Application Output window will show the output from your application.

This works well if your console project does not require any input from the user since the Application Output window cannot handle input, such as from a Console.ReadLine().

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Mac. For me it simply worked:

- Making sure you can run the project on the terminal (in my case Azure functions).
- Ejecting the installer
- (optional) clone again the repo and re-open on Visual Studio.

Then I ran the project again for debug and worked as expected. At this point I think the problem had to do with the installer not being ejected, but I wouldn't be 100% sure.